# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod - Azure Pipeline

Tags: ios, flutter, azure, cocoapods

I migrated one flutter module to my native iOS code. When I trigger the Azure pipeline I am getting this below error,

**[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "airship_flutter":
In Podfile:
airship_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/airship_flutter/ios`)
Specs satisfying the `airship_flutter (from` .symlinks/plugins/airship_flutter/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.**

I can fix it locally by updating version in pod file but I am not able to do the same in Azure automation. Can someone help me how to resolve this issue.